# Generating TExp using Template Haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I'm just getting started with template haskell.

I've written a function that takes a function `a -> [b]` and generates an expression for a function `b -> a`:

```hs
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall -Wextra -Werror #-}
module Surjection where
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Data.Traversable

surj :: (Show a, Show b, Bounded a, Enum a) => (a -> [b]) -> Q Exp -- Q (TExp (b -> a))
surj f = fmap (LamCaseE . concat) .                             -- \case 
  forM [minBound .. maxBound] $ \a -> do
    Just aName <- lookupValueName (show a)
    forM (f a) $ \b -> do
      Just bName <- lookupValueName (show b)
      return $ Match (ConP bName []) (NormalB (ConE aName)) [] --     $(bName) -> $(aName)
```

This works, but it'd be nice if I could promise that it returns a function of that type, that is have it return a `Q (TExp (b -> a))` rather than a `Q Exp`.

Everything I've seen thus far about generating typed expressions uses splices and quasiquotes. Is there a way to generate it from template haskell constructors?

Answer (score 1):

Oh hey, there's a [`TExp :: Exp -> TExp a` constructor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.15.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:TExp) in `Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax`, so I can just use that:

```hs
surj f = fmap (TExp . LamCaseE . concat) ...
```

There's the downside that the type specified by `TExp` only gets checked at splice time (kind of like a C++ template), but that's inherent to TH.

Comment: While this works, it's basically circumventing the exact benefits that using typed Template Haskell is supposed to provide.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica : Agreed! I would much rather be able work with primitives like `a -> Q (TPat a)` and `a -> Q (TExp a)` and `TLamCase`, `TMatch`, etc. but those don't seem to exist.

Comment: The only kind of typed things in Template Haskell are typed expressions, not typed patterns, so there's no `TPat`, and so I think it's impossible to make any such primitives.